# TYPO3 fluid template for tcemain hook

Tags: typo3, fluid

TYPO3 6.1

I am writing a tcemain hook for my extbase extension.
I have included that hook php file in "myextension/Classes/Hooks/myTcemainHook.php.
In this hook, I am manipulating datas coming from tca when save the record in backend.
And I am writing that manipulated data to some text file.

Currently I am getting manipulated data in string and writing that string to file like below

```
public function processDatamap_afterAllOperations(&$pObj){
  //Write content to a file
  $textFileCnt = 'Label: '.'manipulated text content, that needs to write to file';
  $textFileCnt .= 'Labe2: '.'manipulated text content, that needs to write to file';
  $file1 =   \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName('fileadmin/printer/printer.txt');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::writeFile($file1, $textFileCnt);
}
```

But here my requirement is to use fluid template for this.
So the file content have to be formatted using fluid template and then should write to file.

How to achieve this? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the standalone view:

http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/How_to_use_the_Fluid_Standalone_view_to_render_template_based_emails

```php
 1 /**
 2 * @param array $recipient recipient of the email in the format array('recipient@domain.tld' => 'Recipient Name')
 3 * @param array $sender sender of the email in the format array('sender@domain.tld' => 'Sender Name')
 4 * @param string $subject subject of the email
 5 * @param string $templateName template name (UpperCamelCase)
 6 * @param array $variables variables to be passed to the Fluid view
 7 * @return boolean TRUE on success, otherwise false
 8 */
 9 protected function sendTemplateEmail(array $recipient, array $sender, $subject, $templateName, array $variables = array()) {
10     /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView $emailView */
11     $emailView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');
12 
13     $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
14     $templateRootPath = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($extbaseFrameworkConfiguration['view']['templateRootPath']);
15     $templatePathAndFilename = $templateRootPath . 'Email/' . $templateName . '.html';
16     $emailView->setTemplatePathAndFilename($templatePathAndFilename);
17     $emailView->assignMultiple($variables);
18     $emailBody = $emailView->render();
19 
20     /** @var $message \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Mail\MailMessage */
21     $message = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Mail\\MailMessage');
22     $message->setTo($recipient)
23           ->setFrom($sender)
24           ->setSubject($subject);
25 
26     // Possible attachments here
27     //foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
28     //    $message->attach($attachment);
29     //}
30 
31     // Plain text example
32     $message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/plain');
33 
34     // HTML Email
35     #$message->setBody($emailBody, 'text/html');
36 
37     $message->send();
38     return $message->isSent();
39 }
```

Comment: I had to add this to work outside of the controller,
$emailView = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView'); instead of this 
$emailView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');